# How can I get my team excited about writing a blog

Tags: management, team

My team has all agreed that writing a company development blog is a good idea. There are a lot of documented benefits to blogging, both for the individuals and the company.

However, while everyone agrees that a blog is a good idea in theory, no one seems to want to actually sit down and write an entry. Between having and endless flow of other work to be done, most of the team being introverts who don't generally like to put themselves out there, and the notion that there's a good chance the blog won't catch on and will be left to rot in some corner of the internet anyway, I'm not really sure how to get people excited about actually getting started. I don't want to just force someone to start writing if they don't want to, it doesn't help anyone to have a hastily written uninformative boring blog. What can I do to get my team excited about actually getting some article written?

Comment: As a quick aside I'm not totally sure if this is the best place for this question, as it really is more management than programming. But then, I'm still unclear as to what questions actually are on topic on programmers.se so I'm giving it a try.

Comment: Well, you could lead by example. Write a few posts, ask for feedback. Then start asking others to take part by suggesting new topics and saying "so who wants to write this post?"

Comment: To help you out with the "best place to ask" thing... Questions about: software requirements,
software architecture and design,
algorithm and data structure concepts,
development methodologies and processes,
software engineering management,
quality assurance and testing, or
software licensing are all probably on-topic.

Comment: On the other hand, any question that includes any phrase having to do with someone's emotional state or thinking process, unrelated to the subject matter areas above, is probably off-topic.  Also, if your question is not specific to the programming profession, it is off-topic.

Comment: It depends. Is it a team of blog authors, or is a team of software developers? What will be the net difference with regard to revenue if they write the blog, or if they don't?

Comment: I am the one who never writes any blog posting about programming - it is all just boring. However Redmine (issue tracking system) make some sort of fun out everyday life of issue opening and closing - sort of like putting checks on shopping list. At least it is some documentation.

Answer (score 4):

### Start writing yourself.

Lead others by being an example for them. Since the team seems motivated, what blocks them is:

- The fear of being the first one to write. The first entry will bring the attention of everyone within the team, and maybe outside of the team.
- The fear of being completely wrong. What if they misunderstood the instructions, and they'll write a purely technical blog entry, while the blog is actually about puppies? Jokes aside, they may not know exactly what are the guidelines, the constraints, etc.
- Hundreds of small details.

  What is the advised length for each blog entry? Are entries with just a few paragraphs allowed? Would a blog post of twenty pages be perceived as boring?

  What if the images are not working or the font they want to pick is available only in the WYSIWYG editor but not outside of it, and their blog post will appear ugly in production?

If you post something yourself, you simply solve all those constraints, and give some hints about what is expected from your coworkers.

Taking the first step is probably the most important factor which prevents people from doing something publicly.

There are still a few other issues to address:

### Manage time.

> [...] having and endless flow of other work to be done [...]

If your team is working on three products at the same time, all three being late for the last four months, indeed, your coworkers won't be inclined to write blog posts. In such case, there are also chances that higher management will perceive such time spending as a loss of time.

Ensure the team has enough time to discuss software-related topics together, learn things, teach them and write about them, and that management fully understands that a software development position doesn't consist in writing as much lines of code as one can.

### Don't expose the information people want to keep private.

> [...] most of the team being introverts who don't generally like to put themselves out there [...]

Most people won't write if it means that their first and family name will appear in the signature.

Ensure they have full control of the personal information which will be shown side by side with their posts. If they want to use a pseudonym, let them do it.

If they are introverts as in "I'm not talking to anybody all day long", there are serious communication issues inside your team which should be addressed first. I can hardly imagine somebody who barely talks to his coworkers starting a blog (unless he's just in a wrong team).

### Popularity doesn't matter.

> [...] and the notion that there's a good chance the blog won't catch on and will be left to rot in some corner of the internet anyway [...]

There are many reasons to write. One of them is being popular. Another one is to learn to write better. Another one is to be able to show to a potential employer that you know stuff by pointing to an article you've written on the subject.

All those reasons go away if there is a risk that the blog project will be abandoned by the company, and the blog will disappear in a few months. It's like working on a project for eight months, and then seeing the management cancelling this project one month before the official release date: all the time you spent on it is perceived as a waste of time.

Discuss clearly with your coworkers the aspects related to intellectual property, copyright, data safety, etc. It should be clear that the blog posts they write are *theirs*, and don't belong to the company. It should be clear that even if the blog doesn't hit 1000 visits per day in the next two months, it will still be online for the last ten years.

If you believe that the blog may become popular, be clear with your team: what makes you think so? How popular is your corporate website? How the blog would be discovered by readers and search engines? Would you use social network to promote the blog?

**But it matters to know the audience.**

Maybe popularity doesn't matter, but your coworkers still need to know *who* will read the blog posts.

Is it nobody, even other members of the team? In this case, motivation would be pretty low. They might want to write stuff in order to use it later when looking for a new job, but chances are, they will simply create their own blogs.

Is the boss reading the blog? What would be the reaction if somebody starts criticizing the company in this blog?

Are other developers from other teams reading the blog? If only the team is reading it, the style of the blog posts would be different, as well as the discussed topics.